# SSIS Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors

Tags: ssis, oledbconnection

Well, I don't how to explain this problem, I have two OLE DB Connections that i need to merge and send to an oledb Destination, the source oledb columns are:

tbl clientes totales:

```
RUT_CLIE numeric(18,0), 
DV(string(1)), CLI_NOM(string(40)), 
CLI_CAT_SUB(string(3)), 
CLI_STA(string(5)), 
CLI_SUB_STA(string(5)), 
**COD_CTR (numeric(18,0))  <- JOIN KEY**, 
nom_ejec(string(50)),
nom_suc(string(100)), 
nom_suc_gpo(string(100)), 
zonal(string(50)), 
id_cargo(string(50)), 
CLI_GRP_NOM(string(25)),  
CANAL(string(50)), 
ACTIVO(int), 
VINCULADO(int), 
VINCULADO_TRX(int), 
CTACTE(int), 
CLI_CAT(string(5))
```

tbl cartera 1 1:

```
cod_cartera (numeric(18,0))  <- JOIN KEY
cargo(string(100)),
nom_suc_gpo(string(100))
```

Destination:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NK91.jpg]

Mapping:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR6Oa.jpg]

I need to convert many of the columns into nvarchar(255), (I think that's the problem), but when I run the program, this happens:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUASR.jpg]

Error Messages:

> [OLE DB Destination [5679]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. 
>   An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21. An OLE DB record
>   is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation
>   generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No
>   work was done.".
>
> [OLE DB Destination [5679]] Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "OLE DB Destination
>   Input" (5692)" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the
>   error row disposition on "input "OLE DB Destination Input" (5692)"
>   specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object
>   of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before
>   this with more information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The
>   ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (5679) failed
>   with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination
>   Input" (5692). The identified component returned an error from the
>   ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the
>   error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The
>   ProcessInput method on component "Sort" (4898) failed with error code
>   0xC0047020 while processing input "Sort Input" (4899). The identified
>   component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is
>   specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the
>   Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted
>   before this with more information about the failure.

Warnings:

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Warning: Warning: Could not open global shared memory
>   to communicate with performance DLL; data flow performance counters
>   are not available.  To resolve, run this package as an administrator,
>   or on the system's console.

Please help, i'm really frustrated and stressed right now, so I can't explain myself better, if you don't understand something, please ask and i'll try to make it better.

Comment: you need to post the details of 'There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.'

Comment: As Beth said, keep looking through the error log (it's very verbose) until you find the actual error. The messages posted above are not useful, there will be something more useful before this.

Comment: Another potentially helpful troubleshooting technique is to redirect the error output of your OLE destination to a flat file, so that you can at least see which records are causing problems.

Comment: Added Warning messages, i'll try with the flat destination if i get something better

Comment: Microsoft error codes suck balls.  They seriously need to simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure without seeing the actual column mappings in your OLE DB destination component, but the fact that `COD_CTR` is defined as NUMERIC(18,0) in `tbl clientes totales` and NVARCHAR(4) in `RUTERO_FICHA_RED` looks highly suspicious.

Comment: Originally its a char(4), i tried changing it to string, int, numeric, but still doesn't work and fail in the same number of rows (7756).
(added mapping)

Answer (score 0):

Edmund Schweppe gave me the idea, the problem was the Data Conversion, I must transform all the metadata into the same oledb destination, like this:
[image]

(Same Data Type as dbo.RUTERO_FICHA_RED table destination).

Thanks for the help!